# Ifelse statement with dataframe subset using date

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I am trying to create a function to apply to a variable in a dataframe that, for a windows of 2 days forward from the current observation, change the value of VarD if in that date window it always take the value 1.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
VarA     VarB     Date         Diff   VarD
 1         1      2007-04-09    NA     0
 1         1      2007-04-10    0      0
 1         1      2007-04-11   -2      1 
 1         1      2007-04-12    0      1  
 1         1      2007-04-13    2      0  
 1         1      2007-04-14    0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-15   -2      1  
 1         1      2007-04-16    1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-17   -4      1  
 1         1      2007-04-18    0      1  
 1         1      2007-04-19    0      1  
 1         1      2007-04-20    0      1
```

The new dataframe should look like the following:

```
VarA     VarB     Date         Diff   VarD  VarC
 1         1      2007-04-09    NA     0      0
 1         1      2007-04-10    0      0      0
 1         1      2007-04-11   -2      1      1 
 1         1      2007-04-12    0      1      1  
 1         1      2007-04-13    2      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-14    0      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-15   -2      1      1  
 1         1      2007-04-16    1      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-17   -4      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-18    0      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-19    0      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-20    0      1      0
```

I have tried the following code:

```
db$VarC <- 0

for (i in unique(db$VarA)) {
 for (j in unique(db$VarB)) {
  for (n in 1 : lenght(db$Date)) {
   if (db$VarD[n] == 0) {db$VarC[n] <- 0}
    else { db$VarC[n] <- ifelse(0 %in% db[(db$Date >=n & db$Date < n+3,]$VarC, 1,0}
}
}
```

But I obtain just zeroes in VarC. I have checked the code without the else and it works fine. No error by r if the complete code is run. I do not have any clue on where the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some alternatives. The first one avoids some messy indexing but the last two do not require any packages.

**1) rollapply** This applies the `VarC` function in a rolling fashion to each 3 elements of `db$VarD`. `align = "left"` says that when it passes `x` to function `VarC` that `x[1]` is the current element, `x[2]` the next and `x[3]` the next, i.e. the current element is the leftmost.  `partial = TRUE` says that if there are not 3 elements available (which would be the case for the last and next to last elements) then just pass however many there are remaining.

```
library(zoo)

VarC <- function(x) if (all(x[-1] == 1)) 0 else x[1]
db$VarC <- rollapply(db$VarD, 3, VarC, partial = TRUE, align = "left")
```

giving:

```
> db
   VarA VarB       Date Diff VarD VarC
1     1    1 2007-04-09   NA    0    0
2     1    1 2007-04-10    0    0    0
3     1    1 2007-04-11   -2    1    1
4     1    1 2007-04-12    0    1    1
5     1    1 2007-04-13    2    0    0
6     1    1 2007-04-14    0    0    0
7     1    1 2007-04-15   -2    1    1
8     1    1 2007-04-16    1    0    0
9     1    1 2007-04-17   -4    1    0
10    1    1 2007-04-18    0    1    0
11    1    1 2007-04-19    0    1    0
12    1    1 2007-04-20    0    1    0
```

**2) sapply**  or using `VarC` from above:

```
n <- nrow(db)
db$VarC <- sapply(1:n, function(i) VarC(db$VarD[i:min(i+2, n)]))
```

**3) for** or using `n` and `VarC` from above:

```
db$VarC <- NA
for(i in 1:n)  db$VarC[i] <- VarC(db$VarD[i:min(i+2, n)])
```

**Note:** The input `db` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "VarA     VarB     Date         Diff   VarD  VarC
 1         1      2007-04-09    NA     0      0
 1         1      2007-04-10    0      0      0
 1         1      2007-04-11   -2      1      1 
 1         1      2007-04-12    0      1      1  
 1         1      2007-04-13    2      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-14    0      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-15   -2      1      1  
 1         1      2007-04-16    1      0      0  
 1         1      2007-04-17   -4      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-18    0      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-19    0      1      0  
 1         1      2007-04-20    0      1      0  "
db <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks G. It works perfectly. I also try with different VarA and if dates are missing, and also worked. One last question: what does it mean the x[-1] in the VarC function? Thanks again.

Comment: `x[-1]` is `x` except for its first element.   Try `x <- c(11, 24, 100); x[-1]`