# Check if a variable return to a previous level in rolling window in r

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to create a function to apply to a variable in a dataframe that, for a windows of 3 days forward from the current observation, calculate if the current price decrease and then return to the original price. The dataframe looks like this:

```
VarA   VarB       Date    Price  Diff  VarD
  1    1     2007-04-09    50     NA   0
  1    1     2007-04-10    50     0    0
  1    1     2007-04-11    48    -2    1
  1    1     2007-04-12    48     0    1
  1    1     2007-04-13    50     2    0
  1    1     2007-04-14    50     0    0
  1    1     2007-04-15    45    -5    1
  1    1     2007-04-16    50     5    0
  1    1     2007-04-17    45    -5    0
  1    1     2007-04-18    48     3    0
  1    1     2007-04-19    48     0    0
  1    1     2007-04-20    50     2    0
```

Where `VarA` and `VarB` are grouping variables (in this example, they do not change), `Price` is the variable I wish to detect if it decrease and then increase again to the starting level, and `Diff` is the lagged price difference (if is of any help).

`VarD` shows the result of applying the function I am trying to guess. There are two conditions for `VarD` to take the value `1`: 1) the price decrease from a level and then, in **any** of the two following days window, returns to the original level (i.e., 50 to 48 and again to 50, in rows 2 to 5, or 50 to 45 and again to 50 in rows 6 to 8); 2) there is a maximum of two days for the price to increase again to the starting level. Otherwise, `VarD` should take the value `0`.

I do not have any clue of how to start.

The dataframe `db` is:

```
db <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ",", text = "VarA,VarB,Date,Price,Diff
1,1,2007-04-09,50,NA
1,1,2007-04-10,50,0
1,1,2007-04-11,48,-2
1,1,2007-04-12,48,0
1,1,2007-04-13,50,2
1,1,2007-04-14,50,0
1,1,2007-04-15,45,-5
1,1,2007-04-16,50,5
1,1,2007-04-17,45,-5
1,1,2007-04-18,48,3
1,1,2007-04-19,48,0
1,1,2007-04-20,50,2")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your requirements correctly:

```
library(dplyr)

db %>%
  #create Diff.2 as helper variable: increase in price from current day to 2 days later
  mutate(Diff.2 = diff(c(Price,NA,NA), lag = 2)) %>% 
  mutate(Var.D = ifelse(
      Diff.2 + lag(Diff.2, 2) == 0 & #condition 1: price increase from current day to 2 days later 
                                     #is cancelled out by price decrease from 2 days ago to current day
      Diff.2 > 0,                    #condition 2: price increases from current day to 2 days later
    1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Var.D = ifelse(is.na(Var.D), 0, Var.D)) %>%
  select(-Diff.2)

   VarA VarB       Date Price Diff Var.D
1     1    1 2007-04-09    50   NA     0
2     1    1 2007-04-10    50    0     0
3     1    1 2007-04-11    48   -2     1
4     1    1 2007-04-12    48    0     1
5     1    1 2007-04-13    50    2     0
6     1    1 2007-04-14    50    0     0
7     1    1 2007-04-15    48   -2     0
8     1    1 2007-04-16    49    1     0
9     1    1 2007-04-17    45   -4     0
10    1    1 2007-04-18    45    0     0
11    1    1 2007-04-19    45    0     0
12    1    1 2007-04-20    50    0     0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just a correction: the price increase to the same level could be in any day in the two days before window (in my case it is a 30 days window). If I understand the code correctly, it will capture only those price changes exactly two days forward, but if the price increase the day after, the code will not consider the change.

Comment: @LeandroZipitria Can you edit your question to clarify these points? It's not exactly obvious at this point. Varying your sample data to show different combinations that result in Var.D = 1 would also help to illustrate that.

Comment: The question and data frame was now clarified.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, if it is of interest. I use inputs from @G. Grothendieck so he deserve most of the credit (but not the blame for errors). The solution is in four steps:

**Step 1:** create a dummy variable equal to 1 if prices decrease and for each month it stays low.

```
db$Tmp1 <- 0

 for (n in 1 : length(db$Date)) db$Tmp1[n] <- ifelse 
  (db$Diff[n] < 0, 1, ifelse (db$Tmp1[n-1:min(0, n)] == 1 && 
   db$Diff[n] == 0, 1, 0))
```

The first part of `ifelse` tells that if price at `date` [n] decrease or if the previous value of `Step1` is equal to 1 and price do not change, then assign the value 1, else 0.

**Step 2:** restrict the number of days the price could be lower in Step 1 to two days (thanks to @G. Grothendieck).

```
loop <- function(x) if (all(x[-1] == 1)) 0 else x[1]
db$Tmp2 = ifelse(db$Diff < 0, rollapply(db$Tmp1, 3, loop, partial = T, 
                 align = "left"), ifelse(db$Diff==0 & lag(db$Tmp2) == 
                   1, 1, 0))
```

`loop` is a function that value 0 if all values -except the current date- are equal to 1, else take the value of `Tmp1`. Then, if the price decrease (`db$diff` < 0) apply `loop` to 3 values of `Tmp1` forward, but if the price do not change and the previous value of `Tmp2` is 1, assign a value of 1. Else assign 0.

**Step 3:** calculate if the price previous to the price decrease is repeated in a three days window from the original price.

```
loop2 <- function(x) if (any(x[-1] == x[1])) 1 else 0
Tmp3 = rollapply(Price, 4, loop2, partial = T, align = "left")
```

The function `loop2` search if any price is repeated in 3 days from the current date (the 4 in the `Tmp3` function). Then, `Tmp3` apply `loop2` to the `Price` vector (following this tread [Ifelse statement with dataframe subset using date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886083/ifelse-statement-with-dataframe-subset-using-date))

**Step 4:** Multiply `Tmp2` and `Tmp3` to obtain the result (and delete the auxiliary variables).

```
db$Sale <- db$Tmp2 * db$Tmp3
db$Tmp1 <- db$Tmp2 <- db$Tmp3 <- NULL
```

Now, `Sale` is just to multiply `Tmp2` and `Tmp3`, as the first one adjust sales to a 3 days windows, and the second one show if the original price at the start of the decrease in price is present at a window of 3 days before.

Hope its useful to anyone.If any has corrections or suggestions, they are very welcome. Lastly, each one of the codes should be applied to each `VarA` and `VarB`, so each step should be in the following code:

```
db <-
  db %>% group_by(VarA, VarB) %>%
  mutate(
code
)
```

The output is:

```
      VarA  VarB   Date     Price  Diff  Tmp1  Tmp2  Tmp3  Sale
     <int> <int>  <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1 2007-04-09    50     0     0    NA     1    NA
 2     1     1 2007-04-10    50     0     0     0     1     0
 3     1     1 2007-04-11    48    -2     1     1     1     1
 4     1     1 2007-04-12    48     0     1     1     1     1
 5     1     1 2007-04-13    50     2     0     0     1     0
 6     1     1 2007-04-14    50     0     0     0     0     0
 7     1     1 2007-04-15    48    -2     1     1     0     0
 8     1     1 2007-04-16    49     1     0     0     0     0
 9     1     1 2007-04-17    45    -4     1     0     1     0
10     1     1 2007-04-18    45     0     1     0     1     0
11     1     1 2007-04-19    45     0     1     0     0     0
12     1     1 2007-04-20    50     5     0     0     0     0
```

Thanks a lot.